# Polyglossia: equivalent to \NoAutoSpacing?

Tags: xetex, verbatim, polyglossia, french

I use `polyglossia` in XeLaTeX with the french language.

When I type verbatim text, with `\verb|...|`, the space before a `:` is not removed. For exemple, I get `http ://` for web URLs...

In Babel, I could use `\NoAutoSpacing` to disable such autospacing, but there doesn't seem to be this command in `polyglossia`.

How can I do to not have this space?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you tried encasing URL strings in a `\url{...}` wrapper?

Comment: It seems pretty normal to me that, if you're typing a ` ` within  a `\verb|...|` command, the space will be printed, doesn't it? The fact that this space is introduced in the url might come from your text editor: I'd rather dig in this direction, than fiddling with `\verb` behavior.